# Stored procedure won't return any error message or number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

Here is my insert stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spainsert 
    @A_Name nvarchar(50) 
AS BEGIN 
   BEGIN TRY
      DECLARE Detailed_Error VAR_CHAR(MAX); 

      Insert into A(A_Name) 
      values(A_Name) 
   END TRY 
   BEGIN CATCH
       SELECT 
          Detailed_Error = CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VAR_CHAR ) + ' : '+ ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' : ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VAR_CHAR );
   END CATCH 
END
```

When I try to enter NUMBER instead of NAME : `exec spa insert 500`, it won't show any error, but just saves that row into table. Could you please help me how to handle errors, how to know the number and the error message ?!

Thank you all !
123456787523535464654645654651541541255435.4153241653241636524165324135

Comment: It looks like you have forgot to include your stored procedure text in  question.

Comment: CREATE proc dbo.spainsert  AName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY

DECLARE DetailedError VARCHAR(MAX);

Insert into A(AName)values(AName)

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

SELECT DetailedError =         
  CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR ) + ' : '+
  ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' : ' +
  CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS     VARCHAR );

END CATCH
END

Comment: **[edit]** your question, and use the `{}` button when the code is highlighted.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Im sorry but ,the editor wont let me edit the text ,neither to use {} or '@' symbol

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: im using mssql database

Comment: Make a fully functional test case.  How do you create the database table, what are you trying to execute your stored procedure?  If someone can run your entire code sample to see what you are seeing it would make it easier for them.

Comment: Sorry but ,i must use '_' or spaces in the middle of some words or '@'symbol because the editor wont let me post the question!

Comment: Include mssql in the question title and/or tag the question with mssql.

Comment: I dont know , i didnt enter that word SERVER

Comment: So , when i try to execute it : exec spainsert 500 (and not a Name) , it saves that row into table , and wont return any sql error message like : you are entering wrong type of data ,@AName doesn`t expect int ,or i dont know

Comment: It just implicitly casts 500 to "500"

Comment: How to avoid that , i mean how to restrict it , to save only NAMES (Letters) to database and not Numbers or something else .Is it happening that @A_Name is nvarchar(50) and it should be varchar(50) ?

Comment: @Çova: the official name for the Microsoft relational database product is **SQL Server** - not "mssql", nor "MS-SQL" nor anything like that. And "SQL" is just the **query language** - not the actual database product

Answer (score 1):

The thing is `Sql Server` implicitly casts integer value to `varchar` value. So 500 is casted to '500'. If you want to validate you should validate inside your stored proc:

```
IF @A_Name LIKE '%[^a-z ]%'
   RAISERROR('Name contains some incorrect symbols', 16, 1)
```

This will throw error if name contains symbols other then `a--z, A--Z, ' '`.

Comment: Thank you ! Could you please help me how to handle errors, if an error is thrown how to output to the user the number and the error message ?!Example: invalid data,invalid data types , constrains,foreign key,primary key doesnt exist etc

Comment: @Çova, you have implemented some correct error handling. Do you have any problem with that?

Comment: Yes , spainsert expects a NAME parameter ,and when i execute exec spainsert 'test' ->it saves that row and it is OK
when i execute exec spainsert 5000 ->it saves that row too ,and it`s not OK because it is a number ,so i want to get for every error the number and the message too,in the output!

Comment: @Çova, did you try my statement? Doesn't it throws error where you pass 500 to your proc??

Answer (score 0):

You insert query should be wrong.Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spainsert 
    @A_Name nvarchar(50) 
AS BEGIN 
   BEGIN TRY

      Insert into A(A_Name) 
      values(@A_Name) 
   END TRY 
   BEGIN CATCH
       SELECT 
           CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VAR_CHAR ) + ' : '+ ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' : ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VAR_CHAR )
   END CATCH 
END
```

Comment: So , when i try to execute it : exec spainsert 500 (and not a Name) , it saves that row into table , and wont return any SQL error message like : you are entering wrong type of data ,@AName doesn`t expect int ,or i dont know.

How to avoid that , i mean how to restrict it , to save only NAMES (Letters) to database and not Numbers or something else .Is it happening that @A_Name is nvarchar(50) and it should be varchar(50) ?

Comment: keywords and table names are correct , i used SPACES or UNDERSCORES ,because the STACKOVERFLOW EDITOR didnt let me post the question , so i removed the '@' symbols and break-up some words

Comment: Thank you ! Could you please help me how to handle errors, if an error is thrown how to output to the user the number and the error message ?!Example: invalid data,invalid data types , constrains,foreign key,primary key doesnt exist etc

Comment: If it is help full to given vote.More details to refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175976.aspx.